# Subroutine not working, error message saying variable is not defined

Tags: python, subroutine

i am using a subroutine and i think it is the cause of my problem, here is my code :

```
def sub1():
    dob=input('Please enter the date of the person (dd) : ')
    while dob not in ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31']:
        print('you have entered an incorrect day')
        dob=input('Please enter the date of the person (dd) : ')
sub1()
if month == '02' :
    if dob == ['30','31'] :
        print('You have entered incorrecty')
        sub1()
```

The variable month is just 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12

The error message is :
 File "C:/Users/Akshay Patel/Documents/TASK 2/task two month dob.py", line 13, in 
    if dob == ['30','31'] :

NameError: name 'dob' is not defined

Comment: fix your indentation... it makes a difference in python.  Your error message makes it sound like your indentation is correct in your original source.  ``dob`` is only defined within ``sub1`` so when you use it outside of ``sub1`` it's not there for you

Answer (score 2):

The variable `dob` is local to `sub1` and hence you cannot see it at global scope.

You might want to return it:

```
def sub1():
    dob=input('Please enter the date of the person (dd) : ')
    while dob not in ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31']:
        print('you have entered an incorrect day')
        dob=input('Please enter the date of the person (dd) : ')
    return dob ###########
dob = sub1() ########
if month == '02' :
    if dob in ['30','31'] : ######### in not ==
        print('You have entered incorrecty')
        dob = sub1() ##############
```

---

I personally would refactor your code a bit:

```
def inputDay (month):
    #february doesn't respect leap years
    maxDay = [42, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31] [month]
    dob = 0
    while dob > maxDay or dob < 1:
        dob = int(input('Please enter day of month: '))
    return dob

month = 2 #change this value accordingly
day = inputDay(month)
print('{}/{}'.format(month, day))
```

---

If at some moment you want to input a whole date, you can consider using this:

```
from datetime import datetime

def inputDate():
    while True:
        try: return datetime.strptime(input('Enter date (m/d/yyyy): '), '%m/%d/%Y')
        except ValueError: pass

a = inputDate()
print(a.day, a.month, a.year)
```

Comment: so what do i have to do?

Comment: @ap306 See the rest of my answer.

Comment: Also need to indent after while loop

Comment: @advert2013 Thank you. Copypasta from original post.

Comment: thank you i will try it and post the results if it works or doesnt work

Comment: so for if dob in ['30','31'] : do you mean i have to type if dob in not == ['30','31'] :

Comment: @ap306 The correct line reads `if dob in ['30', '31']`. As `in` checks for containment. You can also use a tuple instead of the list.

Comment: please explain 3rd line of your code?. (maxDay ect.)

Comment: @ap306 It determines the maximum day of the given month `month`. 31 for january, 31 for july, 30 for septembre, etc. It does not respect leap years. If you need support for leap years, look at my last edit.