# Adding up different values

Tags: python

I need to add up different values that the user has entered for a date of birth, so for example in a shorter code:

```
year = input('Enter the year he/she was born in (yyyy) : ')
month = input('Enter the month he/she was born in (mm) : ')
day = input('Enter the day he/she wa born in (dd) : ')
```

Now how do I add up all these values to make it be dd/mm/yyyy

Can the ending result be called fulldob please

(this is not the whole code and so not as complicated)

Please assist

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Dear Akshay Patel, what happened to the answers to your previous questions (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052625/subroutine-not-working-error-message-saying-variable-is-not-defined). None was of help to you?

Comment: @Hyperboreus Yes, the answer to the previous question worked, but i used the first answer and not the second because it was to complicated for me

Answer (score 0):

As already answered to your last question, why re-invent the wheel? Python provides date/time manipulation in the standard library, so just use it. So you are sure that the day of month is within range, that leap years are taken care of, etc.

```
from datetime import datetime

def inputDate():
    while True:
        try: return datetime.strptime(input('Enter date of birth (m/d/yyyy): '), '%m/%d/%Y')
        except ValueError: pass

a = inputDate()
print(a.day, a.month, a.year)
print(a.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')) #your desired format
```